# How to find Which SQL Query is Best in below Query.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**For Select duplicates rows only.**

```
CREATE TABLE #JEBIN(ID INT, SAL INT)
INSERT INTO #JEBIN (ID,SAL) VALUES (1,10),(2,30),(2,30),(4,40),(5,60),(5,70)
SELECT * FROM #JEBIN
```

First Query using CTE

```
;WITH CTE As
(
   SELECT ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By SAL  Order By ID Desc)as cosal,sal FROM #JEBIN
)
SELECT * from CTE where cosal>1
```

Second Query uses aggregate functions

```
SELECT ID,SAL FROM #JEBIN GROUP BY ID,SAL HAVING (COUNT(id)>1)
```

How to performance tune above two queries.?

Is using the SQL Execution Plan. But not aware about it. But both queries same cost?

Comment: Those are not logically the same queries. So comparing their performance does not seem like a useful action. With your trivial sample data, you might not see the logical difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most common ways to do a quick comparison of the performance of two queries in SQL Server is to turn on `STATISTICS` for your session(s). There are two that tend to be most informative; [`SET STATISTICS TIME ON|OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`SET STATISTICS IO ON|OFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

You can activate both with one line of code above your query or queries.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME, IO ON;
```

After the code block, I typically turn them back off.

```
SET STATISTICS TIME, IO OFF;
```

The information from this will print in the `MESSAGES` tab of your query window. In order to make them easier to read, you can take them over to Ritchie Rump's convenient [Statistics Parser](http://statisticsparser.com/) page.

Comment: Yeah, except when comparing apples to oranges metrics are useless - the queries are not even removely doing the same thing.

Comment: @TomTom, at least he'll know if the apple weighs more than the orange...

Answer (score 0):

#### First Query using CTE

It scans the whole table, sorts (EXPENSIVE), assigns row_number, scan once more to compare the row_number with 1.

#### Second Query using GROUP BY

It scans the whole table piping to aggregation, compare the count

The second query is faster if your table is not indexed. Sorting in first query is really expensive.

The First Query outputs the duplicating rows the number of times it duplicates. But nevermind, it is easy to align by adding distinct as the final step.

Answer (score 0):

Please add "explain" before your query

Ex- explain select * from table_name

result of query-

```
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+

| id | select_type | table         | type  | **possible_keys | key**     | key_len | ref   | **rows** | Extra |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | merchant_link | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const |    1 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+---------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+
```

If the number of row in explain query is less, it means it's faster. Plus you will get information about which key is picked

Answer (score 0):

Often the fastest is a correlated subquery with the right index:

```
select j.*
from #jebin j
where exists (select 1
              from #jebin j2
              where j2.sal = j.sal and j2.id <> j.id
             );
```

You want an index on `(sal, id)`.